# Travelling before and after 30 day grace period of J1 Visa

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, canada

I'm in a bit of a pickle. Due to miscalculation, I'll be entering 31 days (instead of 30 days) before the start of my J1 program. I also leave 5 days after the 30 day grace period after the end of my J1 program.

My question is:

Will I be able to enter U.S. under VWP (I have an Australian Passport), and during the month before my program start I intend to travel the West Coast up to Cananda, and then re-enter on my J1 visa.

Similarly, after the end of my program, during the grace period, I intend to travel East Coast up to Canada and then re-enter under the VWP program such that I can leave the U.S. a few days after my grace period finishes.

Comment: What could possibly go wrong? Seriously, don't do any of this, you're just inviting a world of trouble. Even Olivia Newton-John got deported back to Oz and unlike her you can't call ambassadors.

Comment: It's much, much easier (and cheaper!) to change your flight itinerary now, than to change it after you've been refused entry.

Comment: Just checked with united airlines, about $1000 to change my flight...

Comment: I have decided to take the less risky route and get a B2 visa which will allow for travel before and after the grace periods.

Comment: What does the visa give you that the VWP doesn't? The related duplicate and particularly it's answer (http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/17175/19400) leave me with the distinct impression that your original plan is fine as it is. @TheMathemagician do you have details of Olivia Newton-John's deportation? Google isn't helping. Whatever it was, I am fairly confident it had nothing whatsoever to do with the J-1 program, and probably not the VWP, either.

Comment: Oops my bad. It wasn't ONJ - it was a young female Australian journalist trying to interview ONJ. ONJ did call the ambassador though. "One young Australian woman reporter flew out to interview Olivia Newton-John without a visa and was handcuffed, detained and body-searched for 15 hours before being shunted back to Sydney." It happened in 2003.

Comment: However my point is that if your visa allows you to enter 30 days before the start date and you show up 31 days before, or overstay by 5 days, you are taking the risk that US Immigration deports you and makes you apply for a visa for the next ten 10 years. It's just not worth the risk.